# Django - Filter for objects with field that is bigger than limit value

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset

I want to filter for objects whose id is bigger than one that I've specified.

This is what I am looking for:

```
const LIMIT_ID = 100

bigIdPeople = Person.objects.filter(id > LIMIT_ID)
```

Is this possible and how should I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: I suggest reading [Making Queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/) in the docs. especially the section on [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
bigIdPeople = Person.objects.filter(id_gte=LIMIT_ID)
# this means 'greater than or equal to'
# if you want 'greater than', you can change 'gte' to 'gt'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Reminder that you need two underscores in order to use `gte`: `Person.objects.filter(id__gte=LIMIT_ID)`